# Cron job failed without a reason

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, google-app-engine, cron

I am in a situation where I have a CRON task on google app engine (using flex environment) that just dies after **some** time, but I have no trace WHY (checked the GA Logs, nothing, tried try/catch, and explicitly log it - no error).

I have explicitly verified that if I create a cron task that runs for 8 minutes (but doesn't do much - just sleeps and updates database every second), it will run successfully. *This is just to prove that CRON jobs can at least run 8 minutes if not more.* & I have set up the Express & NodeJS combo up correctly.

This is all fine, but seems that my **other** cron job dies in 2-3 minutes, so quite fast. It is hitting some kind of limit, but I have no idea how to control for it, or even what limit it is, so all I can do is speculate.

I will tell more about my CRON task. It is basically rapidly querying MongoDB database where every query is quite fast. I've tried the same code locally, and there are no problems.

My speculation is that I am somehow creating too many MongoDB requests at once, and potentially running out of something?

Here's a pseudocode (just to describe what kind of scale data we're talking about - the numbers and flow are exactly the same):

```
function q1() {
      return await mongoExecute(async (db) => {
        const [l1, l2] = await Promise.all([
            db.collection('Obj1').count({uid1: c1, u2action: 'L'}),
            db.collection('Obj1').count({uid2: c2, u1action: 'L'}),
        ]);

        return l1+l2;
    });
}

for(let i = 0; i < 8000; i++) {
   const allImportantInformation = Promise.all([
       q1(),
       q2(),
       q3(),
       .....
       q10()
   ])

   await mongoDb.saveToServer(document);
}
```

It is getting somewhere around `i=1600` before the CRON job just dies without any explanation. The GA Cron Job panel clearly says the JOB has failed.

Here is also my mongoExecute (which is just a separate module that caches the db object, which hopefully is the correct practice in order to ensure that mongodb pooling works correctly.)

```
import { MongoClient, Db } from 'mongodb';

let db = null;
let promiseInProgress = null;

export async function mongoExecute<T> (executor: (instance: Db) => T): Promise<T | null> {

    if (!db) {
        if (!promiseInProgress) {
            promiseInProgress = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                const tempDb = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL);
                resolve(tempDb);
            });
        }

        db = await promiseInProgress;
    }
    try {
        const value = await executor(db);
        return value;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

What would be the solution? My idea is to basically ensure less requests are made at once (so all the promises would be sequential, and potentially add sleep between each cycle in the FOR.

I don't understand because it works fine up until some specific point (and quite big point, it's definitely different amount, sometimes it is 800, sometimes 1200, etc).

Is there any "running out of TCP connections" scenario happening? Theoretically we shouldn't run out of anything because we don't have much open at any given point.

**It seems to be working if I throw 200ms wait between each cycle** & I suspect I can figure out solution, all the items don't have to be updated in the same CRON execution, but it is a bit annoying, and I would like to know what's going on.

Is the garbage collector not catching up fast enough, why exactly is GA silently failing my cron task?

Comment: My guess is the `MongoClient.connect()` code is being called in rapid-fire manner thus the job is eating too much TCP connection, since `connect()` in the node driver creates a connection pool containing 5 connections by default. This could explain why putting a 200ms wait makes it work, since the code found that the `db` is not null anymore, thus it's not rapid-firing the `connect()` method and properly uses the existing connection pool. Essentially without the wait, the code quickly creates a lot of connection pools. With the wait, it creates only one connection pool.

Comment: You can check if this is indeed the case by moving the `MongoClient.connect()` code outside of `MongoExecute` into the main part of the code. Pass in the `db` object into each `q()` functions. This is best practice anyway, `MongoClient.connect()` is supposed to be called only once per app execution, since it creates a connection pool instead of a single connection to the database.

Comment: That's an interesting theory, although to my understanding the execution going on in the CRON job is single threaded (because JS is single threaded), which means there is no race condition (and MongoClient.connect should be called only once). However, it doesn't really hurt to actually test it so I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I tried it, but it is like expected: the mongoExecute() only ever creates single connection at apps lifetime, no matter how fast mongoExecute() is being executed. I also fixed the issue by updating mongodb driver.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what the bug is, and fixed it accordingly.

Let me rephrase it; I have no idea what the bug was, and having no errors at any point was discouraging, however I managed to fix (lucky guess) whatever was happening by updating my nodejs mongodb driver to the latest version (from 2.xx -> 3.1.10).

No sleeps needed in my code anymore.